# Dynamically adding JS block in VB.NET code behind

Tags: javascript, vb.net

I am working on a system that administers a number of pages to end users for data entry.  There is a need to prevent the back button (I know, not ideal, but that is the requirement), but to disable this 'block' when viewing the pages in test mode.

I have the necessary JS and it works for what we need, but I'm having issues adding the code dynamically to the page so that it fires.

What do I mean by this?  Well, I can get the code block added dynamically so it *looks* exactly as it should, but the code doesn't work. If I copy and paste the text and manually add it to the aspx page (so not using code behind to do it), it works fine.

Here's the JS to work-around the back button click:

```
> <script type="text/javascript">
>       function preventBack(){window.history.forward();} setTimeout("preventBack()", 0); window.onunload=function(){null};
>     </script>
```

In my `aspx.vb` code behind file I have the following:

```
If Not TestMode Then
  ' add JS
End If
```

I have tried adding the JS in the following ways - none of which seem to have worked:

1. `Page.RegisterClientScriptBlock("preventBack", "<script type=""text/javascript"">function preventBack(){window.history.forward();} setTimeout(""preventBack()"", 0); window.onunload=function(){null};</script>")`
2. Dim scriptText As New StringBuilder

   ```
   scriptText.Append("<script type='text/javascript'>")
   scriptText.Append("function preventBack(){")
   scriptText.Append("   window.history.forward();} ")
   scriptText.Append("setTimeout('preventBack()', 0); ")
   scriptText.Append("window.onunload=function(){null};")
   scriptText.Append("</script>")
   ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page.GetType, "noback", scriptText.ToString, False)
   ```
3. Dim lit As New Literal

   ```
   lit.Text = "<script type='text/javascript' src='JS/noBack.js'>"  '"<script type='text/javascript'>function preventBack(){window.history.forward();} setTimeout('preventBack()', 0); window.onunload=function(){null};</script>"
   Head1.Controls.Add(lit)
   ```
4. Dim gc As New HtmlGenericControl

   ```
   gc.TagName = "script"
   gc.Attributes.Add("type", "javascript")
   gc.Attributes.Add("src", "JS/noBack.js")
   Head1.Controls.Add(gc)
   ```
5. `ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), "MyScript", "JS/noBack.js", True)`

Where the noBackJS file contains the JS code mentioned above.

As I said, the actually code is written to the HTML on the page when rendered, but doesn't work/fire at all.  Clearly I'm missing something here, but can't for the life of me work out what it is, can anyone help please?

Thx.

Comment: Have you tried `RegisterStartupScript` instead of `RegisterClientScriptBlock` ?

Comment: Hiya - yep, that's #1 above.  Not sure why adding the script reference via code should produce a different result to manually pasting it in - surely it doesn't matter how it gets into the HTML as it's not fired until the client accesses the page...?

Comment: In #1 u also used `RegisterClientScriptBlock`, what I meant is to try `RegisterStartupScript` instead - have you tried that?

Comment: ah, sorry, yes tried that too.  Tried it in the same way as in #1 and also same as #2 with same result

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
Dim jScript As String = "<script>alert('')</script>"
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "Registered Script", jScript, False)
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? Please add an explanation of what you did and why you did it that way not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `eval()`, for example:

```
eval($("#mytextbox").val())
```